# Android How to position Items in a Toolbar

Tags: android-layout

I understand the one of the advantages of the toolbar over the action bar is the ability to position and add items. However I cannot figure out how to position these items on the toolbar where I would like to. I have 6 items and i want three of the items aligned to the left a space in the middle and the other three aligned to the right.

Comment: Did the answer I post work for you?

Comment: the space widget did not work but adding a linear layout inside the toolbar did thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Space` widget for this.

Add a `LinearLayout` inside your `Toolbar`. I am adding 6 `TextViews` inside this `LinearLayout`. You can, of course, change it according to your requirement.

Now to align 3 of the child views to the left and 3 to the right simply add a `android.support.v4.widget.Space` widget after the third child view and set it's `layout_weight` property to 1.

Here's the entire toolbar layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="item1"
            android:padding="2dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="item2"
            android:padding="2dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="item3"
            android:padding="2dp"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="item4"
            android:padding="2dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="item5"
            android:padding="2dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="item6"
            android:padding="2dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Hope this works as required for you.